# I am looking to extract html table, match one column value and then click on another column link on the corresponding matched row in Ruby Automation

Tags: ruby, automation, nokogiri

I am new to Ruby and still in beginners phase and struggling to accomplish this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
I am using nokogiri to parse this table, find select activity match and then click on Details link on another column of matched row

```
<tbody>
 <tr class="GridRowOdd">
  <td align="centre" title="Select Activity">
    <a class="gridLink" title="Select Activity"
     href="https://something/something.context=Level-1&selectedRow=1">payment</a>
  <td>
  <td align-"centre">02/21/2018</td>
  <td align-"centre">$8.47</td>
  <td align-"centre" title="Details">
    <a class="gridLink" title="Details"
     href="https://...something/something.context=Level-
      1&selectedRow=1">Details</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="GridRowEven">
  <td align="centre" title="Select Activity">
    <a class="gridLink" title="Select Activity"
     href="https://something/something.context=Level-1&selectedRow=2">Loan Activity</a>
  <td>
  <td align-"centre">02/21/2018</td>
  <td align-"centre">$8.47</td>
  <td align-"centre" title="Details">
    <a class="gridLink" title="Details"
     href="https://...something/something.context=Level-
      1&selectedRow=2">Details</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I tried this, it's finding the match, but clicking on first Details link always(which I understand that I am not iterating and finding the right row and column to click on it, but I am not sure how to do that)

```
require ópen-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
link(:details_link, :title => "Details")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(html)
table = doc.xpath('//table//tbody//tr[3]//td[2]//table//tbody//tr[2]//td//'
if table.include? "Loan Activity"
self.details_link
end
```

Comment: May I know which automation tool are you using? I know how to accomplish this without the help of nokogiri.

Comment: I am just using Watir and scripting in Ruby. When I was looking for the solution, learnt about nokogiri for html tables, so thought of using it. I don't require to use nokogiri as long as I find another working solution if u can help me to crack it up.

Comment: Okay i will update the answer now.

Comment: Hi, which column has Loan Type activity? I don't find any column which has load Type activity, Can you update the full  table here?

Comment: Can you give me more detail? In the place of `payment` You can choose Loan Type Activity?

Comment: ...and what's the table id?

Comment: Hi, Raj, there is no ID for the table, so I am just getting it using xpath. Loan Activity is just the value of first td(column) under tr which I am matching against.  So if first column value matches "loan activity"(variable), then click on the corresponding "Details" link

Comment: But I find only Payment, no 'payment activity', Can you please put the correct spelling of 'Payment Activity' and 'Load Activity'? Spelling is important while we choose. 

Or is it only Payment Or Loan only appears which you need to check?

Comment: I couldn't post the entire html, because it's in my remote desktop where I can't access stackoverflow. So I typed this html. this is the xpath ('//table//tbody//tr[3]//td[2]//table//tbody//tr[2]//td//') I am using to get the entire table.

Comment: I posted an answer below, check out and let me know whether it works. I assume loan or payment appears in one of the column as link.

Comment: Since you updated the question, I updated the answer as well, I changed string from loan to Loan Activity. Please look at that.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I updated. I will try this code and post the updates. Thank You

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer by ticking the arrow on the left top If it helps you. :(

Comment: Sure, Thanks for letting me know.. this is my first time using stackoverflow. I am just waiting for my environment to be up to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new

b.goto 'paste your URL here'

#I assume only one table appear so I used the below xpath

b.table(xpath: '//table').rows.each do |row|
  if row.cell(text: 'Loan Activity').exists?
    row.cell(text: 'Details').click
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ My answer is the the continuation of the question and also the continuation of comments as well! People those come here for an answer read the question first, even if they do not read the question the answer will force them to read the question for complete understanding of the problem.

Comment: Hi Raj, I used xpath to get the table, but getting error as table is not located false. I am not sure why it's not recognizing the table. but when I use nokogiri it's getting the table with the same xpath where as getting undefined error for 'rows'

Comment: @Nisha, Do you have team viewer connection, Can I have control?

Comment: @Nisha The problem you have done is, you haven't located your table properly, If you locate your table properly, then everything will work fine. check `b.table(xpath: "putyourxpath").exist?` returns true, if it's not you haven't even located the table properly.

Comment: @RAJ how silly I am.. you are so helpful and this code worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Raj , I am trying to put else statement                          b.table(xpath: '//table').rows.each do |row|
  if row.cell(text: 'Loan Activity').exists?
    row.cell(text: 'Details').click else p "Loan Activity Not Exists"
  end
end, but it always hits else statement only though if statement pass. Can you please help me to understand why it's always going to else block though Loan Activity presents in table.

Comment: @Nisha Tomorrow morning I will look into your problem

Comment: @RAJ sure Thank You

Comment: @Nisha No it works fine for me. No problem. I used your code, when if condition passed, then it clicked the link, If not, it goes to print the else case. I don't fine any issue

`b.table(xpath: '//table').rows.each do |row|
  if row.cell(text: 'Loan Activity').exists?
    row.cell(text: 'Details').click
  else
    p "Loan Activity Not Exists"
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with css like this:

```
url = table.at('td:has(a:contains("Loan Activity")) ~ td[title=Details] a')[:href]
```

That `~` fyi matches following siblings

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error after trying this code "undefined method `at' for #<String:0x00000000053b6028> (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Why is table a string? Try doc.at in that case.

Comment: I gave the wrong xpath for table. Corrected it now and it's working fine. Thank You